# Opensuse 11.4 repos

Tags: opensuse

I need to install python2.7 on Opensuse 11.4. I cant find  repo for that. Even cant find git repo. Where sould i search for it ?
I tried:

```
http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/discontinued/distribution/11.4/repo/oss/ 
http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/discontinued/update/11.4/rpm/i586/
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/11.4:/Contrib/standard/
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/11.4:/Live/standard/
```

But cant find not git not python2.7.

Answer (score 0):

The [SUSE Open Build Service](https://software.opensuse.org/package/python?search_term=%22python%22) usually is the place to look.  It shows two "unstable" repos containing Python 2.7.  You may need to select your OS (OpenSuse 11.4) on the search page.  The more promising of the two is [`systemsmanagement:saltstack:products:testing`](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/systemsmanagement:/saltstack:/products:/testing/SLE_11_SP4)